# Nominate other users for moderator election

Tags: support, moderator-elections, election

Is it possible to nominate other users in the moderator election, or can you only nominate yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the election page it says

> In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with more than 300 reputation may **nominate themselves** to be a community moderator.

There has been some discussion of the use of the term "nomination" [on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75438/change-nominate-to-volunteer), but [Jeff has explained](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/what-is-the-reason-for-insisting-on-self-nomination) the rationale for only allowing self nominations on the Mathematics Meta, which I believe was the first site to use the election software.

You can encourage others to nominate themselves through chat or other communication channels, but they must be the ones to put themselves forward as candidates.